# Selecting a column2 if column1 is not matching the required criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

It seems i am unable to find a efficient way to solve this problem with a oracle SQL query.

Please share your suggestions.

I have the below table.

| Descr | Code1 | Code2 | Code3 | Code4 | Code5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | A | AA | aa | Ap | Ae |
| Apple | C | AA | aa | Ap | Ae |
| Apple | A | DD | aa | Ap | Ae |
| Mango | M | MA | mn | mg | mo |

I would use a Query

```
Select Desc from myTable where Code1='A'
```

Above query would give me 'Apple' as the response

```
Select Desc from myTable where Code2='AA'
```

Above query would again give me 'Apple' as the response

Combining both:

```
Select Desc from myTable where (Code2='AA' or Code1='A')
```

How can i know due to which colum has the "OR" condition satisfied ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test in the `select`:

```
Select t.Desc,
       (case when Code2 = 'AA' then 'Code2'
             when Code1 = 'A' then 'Code1'
        end)
from myTable t
where Code2 = 'AA' or Code1 = 'A';
```

If you want to see *both* if both match, then tweak the logic:

```
Select t.Desc,
       trim(',' from
               (case when Code2 = 'AA' then ',Code2' end) '||'
               (case when Code1 = 'A' then ',Code1' end)
           ) as columns
from myTable t
where Code2 = 'AA' or Code1 = 'A';
```

You can also use a lateral join, subquery, or CTE to define `columns` only once:

```
Select t.Desc, c.columns
from myTable t cross join lateral
     (select trim(',' from
                   (case when Code2 = 'AA' then ',Code2' end) '||'
                   (case when Code1 = 'A' then ',Code1' end)
                 ) as columns
      from dual
     ) c
where columns is not null;
```

Comment: Thank you very much , this solved my problem. And the presentation is excellent.